# SQL Server 2005 Converting Data Type Error

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to import varchar data into a varchar data type field but I am getting a conversion error of varchar cannot be converted to date type bit?   How is that when both fields are already varchar type?

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'JOHN KUCHTA' to data type bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing from CSV, for example, you likely have a missing column in one row, or some of the data is incorrect. Is at least one of the fields you are trying to import of type bit?

Comment: yes there are other fields that are type bit... and I have tried to match all of the types up now that the table is in my database but not in teh production table set.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you are inserting into the wrong column or you have mismatched the columns

Comment: I have checked both tables and both are the same name and both are varchar(30) data types.  SQL let me import the table but now I am trying to import it into Production table and thats where the breakdown is.  I dont know what to try next.  There is only one field named this in the two tables.  What else can I try?  Does that make sense that I already have the table in the database loaded but now I want to add those values from the import into the Production table.  
My SQL code is:

insert PROF
select * from chicago_test

JOELL

Comment: list out the columns, it is possible that the tables don't have the columns in the same ordinal position